# Odd nhibernate question about changing a PK to just an Id field in Mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate

So I need to copy rows for 2 tables from one db to another.

I want to be able to do identity insert, one way is to change the column to not be PK.

if I mark the pk not a pk but just a column, can I still map it as an ID?

Thanks,

E-

Comment: please change the title of the question to something more significative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can map your PK property as an [assigned identifier](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-id-assigned).